# Android Preference add hyperlink in summary

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I'd like to add a hyperlink in the Preference summary, when user tap this, it will open an website in webview, but seems like when I was trying to set a hyperlink in summary like this

```
preference.setSummary(Html.fromhtml(R.string.text_with_hyperlink))
```

The hyper link wont open an website, instead if I am using a SwitchPreference, the toggle will be switch on or off.

Would appreciate for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes that will not work. The same as when used for a TextView like seen in a post last week. Catch the click on it.

Comment: I also tried add a ClickableSpan in the summary, but still not working :(